# Python loop task with countless number additioning

Tags: python

I want to make easy program with loop but can't find out how. I am absolute beginner. So basicly program should add all numbers person writes to it. For example:

```
Person writes: 5

Program shows: 5

Person writes: 6

Program shows: 11

Person writes: 3

Program shows: 14
```

and so on.
This is what I did and it's wrong I don't know how to write it right.

```
while True:
    var1 = int(input("Write a number"))
    var2 = 0 + var1
    print(var2)
```

Comment: Hints: What do you think `var2 = 0 + var1` does, and why did you write that? When and why do you think it might be a good idea to set `var2` to `0`? When and why do you think it might be a good idea to add something to `var2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your sum holder (`var1`) outside the loop and in order to update the sum holder, you should add the newest input to it.

```
>>> var1 = 0
>>> while True:
...    var1 += int( input('Write a number: ') )
...    print(var1)
...

Write a number: 1
1
Write a number: 2
3
Write a number: 4
7
Write a number: -6
1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the code you are looking for, when the user insert a non digit input, i'm printing bad input and the user can try again.

good luck!

```
total = 0
while True:
    try:
        user_input = int(input("enter number"))
    except ValueError:
        print ("bad input, try again")      # in case of the input is not a number
        continue
    total += int(user_input)
    print (total)
```

Comment: As per my guess OP is using  python 3 so no raw _input and print is function

Comment: @VigneshKalai tnx, i fixed it.

Comment: Use a try/except, -5 is a number

Comment: @PadraicCunningham , True that.. fixed.

Comment: it looks really hard to me as it's my first day I am learning to programm but thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
userInput = None # this variable will handle input from user
numberSum = 0 # this is sum of all your numbers
print("Type 'exit' to quit")
while True:
    userInput = input("Enter your number") # here you are taking numbers from user
    if userInput == 'exit': # if user enters 'exit' instead of number, program will call break
        break # break ends loop
    numberSum += int(userInput) # this will add int(userInput) to your numberSum. int() function
                # makes integer type from your String. You have to use it, because
                # while getting input() from user, it's considered as string
print("Your sum is: ")
print(numberSum) # printing your sum
print("byebye...")
```

Note, if you type anything else than 'exit' or number, the program will exit with `ValueError`

Answer (score 0):

In your program each and every time you are updating  var2 value with var1 value so the user input is printed

What you have to do is add the value var1 with var2 value .Initially `var2` value is zero so it is equated to `var1` and so on

```
var2=0
while True:

    var1 = int(input("Write a number"))

    var2 += var1

    print(var2)
```

Comment: now I got it. One more thing I get this error, how to fix it ?

Comment: File "t2.py", line 3                                                                   
    var1 = int(input("Write a number")   ^                                                                                                               
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @Pexlu python is indent based language you have to provide proper indentation and you have use tab or space not both compined